# Reputation not added on Stackoverflow?

Tags: support, reputation

I see on my profile page +15 for a question, however when I click on Reputation, graph does not show this +15.

If I understand profile page shows reputations gained recently and same should be reflected on timelines on graph.

Comment: It's caching. Not everything updated instantly. Give it some time to catch up.

Comment: Thanks for your response, and total reputation is also not reflected, if I understand that is also caching ? Seeing this from last few hours.

Comment: @ChrisF: or look at the right tab; the unaccept/accept combo isn't visible on the *graph* view because there is a net 0 reputation change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone first *un*-accepted your answer, then re-accepted it (the OP unaccepted yours automatically when they [picked the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25329238/timeline), then they changed their mind and picked yours again). The result is that you have a net 0 reputation change:

[image: unaccept then accept]

Because the net result is 0, the unaccept / accept pair is not shown on the graph. You can see them on your [reputation tab sorted by time](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2584700/sachin-thapa?tab=reputation&sort=time) instead.

Comment: Ah. I didn't think of that.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Currently it is showing accepted ? Is there a way to unaccept first and then accept ?

Comment: @SachinThapa: yes, it was *first* unaccepted, *then* accepted again. The *time* tab shows newest events first.